# How to find some string by regex but when special string doesn't adjoin?

Tags: python, regex

Purpose: Find `**` in string and replace it, but exclude when `<center>` and `</center>` adjoins.

Example:

```
**
asdf**adsfds
<cente>**</center>
<center>** </center>
<center> **   </center>
```

In this situation, 1, 2, 3 lines should be replaced, but 4, 5 lines shouldn't be replaced. I've made some regex that negatively matching this things: `(<center> *)\*\*( *</center>)`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably be done with negative lookaheads/lookbehinds, but getting those right is tricky. Here's my suggestion:

```
import re

string = """**
asdf**adsfds
<center>**</center>
<center>** </center>
<center> **   </center>"""
temp = 'specialuniquestring'
string = re.sub(r'(<center>\s*)\*\*(\s*</center>)', r'\1%s\2' % temp, string)
string = string.replace('**', '+++')
string = string.replace(temp, '**')
print(string)
```

Output:

```
+++
asdf+++adsfds
<center>**</center>
<center>** </center>
<center> **   </center>
```

In case you're confused, the value of `string` after the `re.sub` is this:

```
**
asdf**adsfds
<center>specialuniquestring</center>
<center>specialuniquestring </center>
<center> specialuniquestring   </center>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with inverse matching in regex using negative look arounds like below. For further reading [check here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
^((?!\<center\>).)*\*\*((?!\<\/center\>).)*
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `<>`.

Comment: possibly but i thought to check the whole center markup. :)

Comment: You forgot the `/` in the closing tag.

Comment: The `/` also doesn't need to be escaped. Also this doesn't do a replacement with `<center>**O</center>`, but from OP's question it seems it should.